# Copy Node and change Value of an Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, copy

I have the following XML File. I want to copy a new "Test" and change the ID of the Test. How is it possible?

I already can copy the nodes, unfortunately not on the correct position (see images) and I also can´t change the ID.
Anyone have a solution for me?

Before:
[image: XML Now]

After:
[image: XML After]

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(Before.xml");

XmlNode Set = xmldoc.DocumentElement;
string strXmlQuery = "/Toolings/Testing/Test1";

XmlNode NodeToCopy = Set.SelectSingleNode(strXmlQuery);
XmlNode NewNode = NodeToCopy.CloneNode(true);

NodeToCopy.AppendChild(NewNode);

Set.InsertAfter(NewNode, Set.LastChild);

XPathNavigator navigator = xmldoc.CreateNavigator();

navigator.MoveToRoot();
navigator.MoveToFirstChild();
navigator.MoveToFirstChild();
navigator.MoveToFirstChild();
navigator.MoveToFirstChild();
navigator.SetValue("5678");

xmldoc.Save(After.xml");
```

Comment: Are you saying the "Before" is correct? Because the "After" makes more sense.

Comment: At the end, I wanted the "After" one. So the "After" is correct.

Comment: Got it. But do you really want the "Test" to increment? Test1, Test2, etc..? It would complicate consuming your data to do that, they should all just be "Test".

Comment: Yeah you are right! It´s enough when all of them are calling "Test". Without increment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using `System.Xml.Linq.XDocument` which is a much easier API than `XmlDocument`:

```
//You can also use Load(), this is just so I didn't have to make a file
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<Toolings><Testing><Test><ID>1234</ID></Test></Testing></Toolings>");

//Grab the first Test node (change the predicate if you have other search criteria)
var elTest = doc.Descendants().First(d => d.Name == "Test");

//Copy the node, only necessary if you don't know the structure at design time
XElement el = new XElement(elTest);

el.Element("ID").Value = "5678";

//inject new node 
elTest.AddAfterSelf(el);

doc.Save("After.xml");
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution, it works!! ;) But how can I search for the ID, if I dont have an exactly number? So I have a random number in the ID, how can I find the correct place?

Comment: If you mean that you want the new node at the bottom then just use `Last()` instead of `First(d => d......)`. If you need to search a node then you'll have to know something about it that is unique to all of them.